# Which desktops are completely minimalist?

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-environments

I have been searching around at different desktop environments and a couple days ago, I came across a post that listed an environment that was completely blank and the menu was accessed through a right click.

I don't remember what it was called. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check here: http://www.junauza.com/2008/08/20-most-nimble-and-simple-x-window.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the wm2 may have been what I was looking at. And if not, I still have a lot to play around with!

Answer (score 2):

Some environments spring to mind:

- [Window Maker](http://windowmaker.org/) (as mentioned in comments)
- [Enlightenment](http://www.enlightenment.org/) (aka E17)
- You can also access everything from the right click menu in [XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/) (Xubuntu). You could go super-minimalist by disabling all the default panels.